# The opposite of "to fall in love"

Tags: word-request, idiom-request

What is the opposite of **"to fall in love"**? I mean two people fall in love but in a year they stop loving each other.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for *fall **out of** love*.

> [fall out of love (with someone)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+out+of+love)
>   to stop being in love with someone. *She claimed she had fallen out of love with him. He also had fallen out of love.*
>   (TFD)

Here are some examples I pulled from the internet:

> 1. There are seven common warning signs that will help you know if you are **falling out of love** and need to end your relationship, or whether you have the chance of turning things around before you make that final decision.
>      ([Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/randi-gunther/falling-out-of-love_b_6942680.html))
> 2. Well… the only way to really know whether or not you’re in love is to wait and see if you’re starting to **fall out of it**.
>      ([Elite Daily](http://elitedaily.com/dating/signs-falling-out-of-love/1389851/))
> 3. Something is different about the way your partner is acting lately and it has you worried that they might be **falling out of love**.
>      ([Power of Positivity](https://www.powerofpositivity.com/5-signs-partner-falling-love/))
> 4. There are many reasons behind why couples **fall out of love** with each other, or end up getting attracted to some other person.
>      ([LovePanky](http://www.lovepanky.com/love-couch/better-love/falling-out-of-love))

Comment: Can you say **"fall out of love with each other"**? Does it mean **to stop loving**?

Comment: Yeah, that seems ok. If a couple falls out of love, then they no longer love each other. They stopped loving each other. By the way, there is nothing wrong with a longer phrase, like "in a year they stop loving each other" (like you said) or "in a year they are no longer in love".

Comment: I've never heard anyone actually say this. It sort of works on paper, but people don't actually use this phrase when describing why a relationship ended. It would be more like "We fell in love, but after a year we sort of **drifted apart**." or "we **lost the connection**" or "the **spark died**".

Comment: I once wrote a song called "Falling out of love".